# Redirect after checking referrering route in Kohana

Tags: php, referrer, kohana-3.0

I have a Kohana-based website and I want to verify, in a function, where a user comes from. So if he comes from a specific route, I have to redirect him somewhere.

Is there a way to verify what is the route a user comes from (or simply where he comes from) in Kohana 3.0?

Code example:

```
public function action_after_register(){

    if ($this->authlite->logged_in())
    {
        $this->redirect('Home');
    }
    // verify if he comes from a specific route and redirect him accordingly
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
$ref = Request::$referrer;
```

and for getting the route for the ref, you can use `Request::process_uri($referrer_uri, $injected_routes)` with Kohana 3.1 but not in 3.0.

You can add it manually in 3.0: https://gist.github.com/1031396

Injected routes array is optional, if you have a strict list of routes you want to test against (to skip the overhead of comparing to all routes).

Comment: than the referrer is empty :) either your browser has disabled referrer header (web developer toolbar for firefox and similar plug-ins have the habbit to turn it off) or you're accessing the page directly (in which case there is no referrer)

Answer (score 0):

```
Request::$referer
```

should contain the [referer](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Request#property%3areferrer) url.